# Finding the mean from two hash keys

Tags: java, hash, average, mean

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class orde {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  Scanner c1=new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("students.txt")));
  Scanner c2=new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("course1.txt")));
  Scanner c3=new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("course2.txt")));
  HashMap<String,String> M1=new HashMap<String,String>();
  HashMap<String,String> M2=new HashMap<String,String>();
  HashMap<String,String> M3=new HashMap<String,String>();
  add(c1,M1);
  add(c2,M2);
  add(c3,M3);

  for(String key:M1.keySet()) {
    if(M2.containsKey(key))
      System.out.println(key+" "+M1.get(key)+" "+ "course1:"+ " " + M2.get(key)+ " " +  "course2:"+ " " + M3.get(key));
  }
}
private static void add(Scanner c1,HashMap<String, String> M) {
  while(c1.hasNext()) {
    String S[]=c1.nextLine().split(" ");
    M.put(S[0],S[1]);
  }
}
}
```

The output is this:

```
25212 Greg IR101: 70.5 IR102: 72.5
25954 Betty IR101: 70.2 IR102: 63.4
25321 Elsie IR101: 51.5 IR102: 45.6
25654 Chris IR101: 58.6 IR102: 35.1
```

Basically I have used a hash join to join three files together, one contains the student id along with the names, course 1 contains the marks for module 1 and course 2 contains the marks for module 2, but i'm having trouble trying to calculate the average of the two marks (M2 and M3) for example it should look like this when complete:

```
 25212 Greg IR101: 70.5 IR102: 72.5 Average: 71.5
 25954 Betty IR101: 70.2 IR102: 63.4 Average: 66.8
```

Comment: What is the input data?

Comment: it uses three given files and joins then, students.txt gets 25212 and greg, course1.txt gets 70.5 course2.txt gets 71.5

Comment: so basically M2.get(key) = course1.txt  and M3.get = course2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have your values as Strings you can parse them to doubles:

```
String myString = "70.5";
double x = Double.parseDouble(myString);
```

Now you can use this to calculate the average

```
String s1 = "70.5";
String s2 = "72.5";

double m = (Double.parseDouble(s1)+Double.parseDouble(s2))/2d;
System.out.println(m);
```

Note that you can get errors if the value you try to parse is not a number
i.e.

```
String myString="test";
double x = Double.parseDouble(myString); // error
```

For your case a small example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      HashMap<String,String> M1=new HashMap<String,String>();
      HashMap<String,String> M2=new HashMap<String,String>();
      HashMap<String,String> M3=new HashMap<String,String>();
      M1.put("222", "Greg");
      M2.put("222","70.5");
      M3.put("222", "72.5");

      for(String key:M1.keySet()) {
        if(M2.containsKey(key)){
            double average = (Double.parseDouble(M2.get(key))+Double.parseDouble(M3.get(key)))/2d;
            System.out.println(key+" "+M1.get(key)+" "+ "course1:"+ " " + M2.get(key)+ " " +  "course2:"+ " " + M3.get(key)+" average:"+average);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: but do you know how I would set it out, so the average would also be in that loop so it would look like the expected output that I put above

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at orde.main(orde.java:19)

Comment: You shouldn't get an error. I updated the example to be executable. Try it out

Comment: sorry my bad I missed something, thank you very much for the help, I completely forgot about doing it this way